# Send email of my disk space usage daily in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, email, diskspace

I am new to shell scripting.

I wanna send the disk space usage of my machine daily to my email address at a particular time.

What will be the scripting we have to execute?

Comment: Sending email from a script can be done, for instance, by `sendmail`, or (maybe a bit more convenient) by `mutt`, if you have installed it.  BTW, your question is a bit unclear. You should at least post that part of the script, which you already have, so we can know where you got stuck.

Comment: `df | mail -s 'daily disk usage' me@foo.com`